# Uncaught TypeError: (sales_total + sales_vat).toFixed is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Every time I input a quantity it will always give me an error:  (sales_total + sales_vat).toFixed is not a function. Can you please check my code? Here's my full code: https://jsfiddle.net/yv6zks1g/1/

Thanks!

```
$('#sales_qty').keyup(function(){
    var qty = parseFloat($('#sales_qty').val()) || 0;
    var sub_total = parseFloat($('#sales_sub_total').val()) || 0;
    var vat = 0.12;

    var sales_total = $('#sales_total').val((qty * sub_total).toFixed(2)).val();

    var sales_vat = $('#sales_vat').val((sales_total * vat).toFixed(2));

    $('#sales_amount_due').val((sales_total + sales_vat).toFixed(2));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because `sales_total` is a string, as returned from `val()`, and `sales_vat` is a jQuery object. Presumably the latter is missing the call to `val()`, but would then have the same issue as the preceding variable.

To fix this, add the `val()` call on `#sales_vat` to set the variable to the string, then convert them to Number types before making the `#sales_amount_due` calculation. Try this:

```js
$('#sales_qty').keyup(function() {
  var qty = parseFloat($('#sales_qty').val()) || 0;
  var sub_total = parseFloat($('#sales_sub_total').val()) || 0;
  var vat = 0.12;

  var sales_total = $('#sales_total').val((qty * sub_total).toFixed(2)).val();
  var sales_vat = $('#sales_vat').val((sales_total * vat).toFixed(2)).val();

  $('#sales_amount_due').val((+sales_total + +sales_vat).toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Qty: <input type="text" id="sales_qty" /> <br />
Sub total: <input type="text" id="sales_sub_total" value="50" /> <br /><br />

Total: <input type="text" id="sales_total" /> <br />
VAT: <input type="text" id="sales_vat" /> <br /><br />

Due: <input type="text" id="sales_amount_due" value="1.2" /> <br /><br />
```

Better still would be to perform the calculations and store them in variables instead of the DOM elements. That way you're not wasting time by calculating a value as a number, storing it as a string, retrieving it as a string then converting it back to a number again. Try this:

```js
$('#sales_qty').keyup(function() {
  var qty = parseFloat($('#sales_qty').val()) || 0;
  var sub_total = parseFloat($('#sales_sub_total').val()) || 0;
  var vat = 0.12;
  
  var sales_total = qty * sub_total;
  var sales_vat = sales_total * vat; 
  var sales_due = sales_total + sales_vat;

  $('#sales_total').val(sales_total.toFixed(2))
  $('#sales_vat').val(sales_vat.toFixed(2));
  $('#sales_amount_due').val(sales_due.toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Qty: <input type="text" id="sales_qty" /> <br />
Sub total: <input type="text" id="sales_sub_total" value="50" /> <br /><br />

Total: <input type="text" id="sales_total" /> <br />
VAT: <input type="text" id="sales_vat" /> <br /><br />

Due: <input type="text" id="sales_amount_due" value="1.2" /> <br /><br />
```